# MathJax not working in some cases

Tags: support, status-norepro, mathjax

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this question, but I'm experiencing rather strange behavior of MathJax in Google Chrome. On some stackexchange sites the LateX equations don't render. On Physics I can see only the source code:

[image: What I see on physics SE]

However on math.stackexchange.com I can see it perfectly:

[image: what I see on math SE]

These 2 screenshots were taken in the very same browser (Google Chrome under Windows 7) during the same session. Each site is open on different tab - one is working, the other one is not.

When viewing in Firefox, everything is fine. Just Chrome refuses to display equations on physics (and sone other SE sites). Also I tried Chrome on other computers and everything is fine there as well. So the problem must be partially tied to my specific Chrome installation and also somehow tied to certain SE sites (because the same Chromw browser can display equtaions on Math SE).

Do you have an idea why this could be happening?

Comment: Probably a CDN issue, Math.SE uses a slightly newer MathJax version, iirc. Things are working for me, which usually means a CDN problem. Clear your cache and wait for it to resolve itself.

Comment: As an aside, the middle two `$` are superfluous, you can simply type `$\gamma_{ij}g_{\mu\nu}$`.

Comment: @KyleKanos You're right. This was just a dummy test, so I used some 2 arbitrary expressions which don't even belong together.

Comment: I observed a similar thing: I was trying to write `\left<x\middle|p\right>` and it kept "failing to compile" as if `\middle` weren't a TeX command. While I was confused it suddenly started working again.

Comment: @Manishearth Clearing the cache helped. Thank you!

Comment: Hmph. We don't have a [status-at-user's-end] tag.

Comment: @dmckee eh, I think that's usually what [meta-tag:status-norepro] is for